# iOS: Newsstand notification. Is free subscription needed?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, subscription, newsstand-kit

I'm creating a ios newsstand app and have a question regarding subscriptions. I am a little confused regarding the newstand push notification.

I plan to send newsstand push notifications to devices when new issues are available. Do I need to set up a free subscription within the app?

There are varying views I have read online regarding whether all newsstand apps require at least one subscription. I cant see the need to create the free subscription.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a hard requirement from Apple that all NS Apps must have at least one subscription. In case all your content is free you need to create a "Free Subscription" in iTunes. Your app should provide way so that users can subscribe to content in your app. It is recommended that NS Push notification should initiate download only if users are subscribed.

Comment: Can you help me with creating the product-id for Subscription ?